# Python Flask App Error: 'function' object has no attribute 'get' using Flask-Dance

Tags: python, flask, flask-dance

I'm using Flask-Dance for letting the user to login with google. But when I go to the route below it tells me:  'function' object has no attribute 'get'.
What do I do wrong?

If I write "if not google.authorized" it raises an error too.

```
from flask_dance.contrib.google import make_google_blueprint, google
app.register_blueprint(google_blueprint, url_prefix='/login')

google_blueprint = make_google_blueprint(client_id='client_id', client_secret='client_secret')

@app.route('/google')
def google():
   if not google_blueprint.authorized:
      return redirect(url_for('google.login'))
   account_info = google.get("/plus/v1/people/me")
   assert account_info.ok, account_info.text
   return "You are {email} on Google".format(email=resp.json()["emails"][0]["value"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the name of a function

from flask_dance.contrib.google import make_google_blueprint, **google**

def **google**():

Answer (score 0):

You import `google` in line 1, but later on line 7 you define a function `google` which overrides the object from import and essentially hides it, so the line `account_info = google.get("/plus/v1/people/me")` is trying to call get on your function instead of the `google` module you imported.

Rename your function to something else, like `google_endpoint` and it will work.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was doing something similar with the Flask request function. Have spent all day trying to fix it in a bunch of complicated ways, until I read this